# Iwasawa Decomposition for $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

Can someone please direct me to a good reference for Iwasawa decomposition of this Lie group?, I read that I need to use here orthogonalization process of Schmidt from Linear algebra, but I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL%282,R%29.pdf)
  is what google returns first. 
  And, that is Prof.Keith Conrad's notes on this topic.
- This [book](http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/abbaspou/Lie-Book_verrouille.pdf) does the decomposition for $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ and $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$. It has been written by Hossein and Martin and hosted at Max Planck Institute fur Mathematics, Bonn, Germany. And, this covers introductory material on Lie Group Theory!

Comment: Are you on a first name basis with the authors of the book? :D

Comment: @Srivatsan Well, Both of them are professors, the first at University of Nantes and other is a professor at City Univ of NY. I don't even know them!